# How can I find a link between 2 separate SQL tables without knowing the foreign keys?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm relatively new to the SQL game and I'm having a rough time finding a link between tables.

Say I have 4 tables: A, B, C, D.

- Table A has a foreign key to table B.
- Table B has a foreign key to Table C.
- Table C has a foreign key to table D.

There isn't any direct link / relationship between table A and table C, or between B and D or between A and D.

Is there an SQL command or a method of finding the 'path' from table A to table D without knowing anything about table B and C and their respective foreign keys?

Edit: I didn't realize that it may be specific to the type of database but I'm using an Oracle database and connecting to it with SQL Developer.

Comment: Do you not have client software that allows you to simply look?

Comment: No, there isn't. Check information_schema.

Comment: Well I do, but the schema contains 219 different tables. Each table links to several other 2,3 tables, and so on.

Comment: As a grizzled veteran in the SQL game, I would never write a query if I didn't have sufficient knowledge of the tables.  In other words, if I didn't know anything about tables B and C, I'd learn.

Comment: Depending on the database you use, there is some software that will map the tables and their links between on to the other.  They "reverse engineer" the database and display the model.  But there is nothing that will list, on a simple command, the "path" from A to D as you say.  Other than reading the table definitions yourself.

Comment: Perhaps, then, I am approaching this from the incorrect angle.

Comment: Just because you can find a path (or paths) from one table to another in a schema, doesn't mean that that's how you *should* join them. Joins are an expression of an idea - they are the means by which you express what question you're trying to answer. Also, there's no rule that says you must only join tables via links constrained by referential integrity constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in standard sql.

Some DB servers have tools that would help you visualize how to connect the dots. Microsoft Sql server for example has Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio that will allow you to select a table, show tables that references it or tables that the table references. I’m pretty sure that other DBMS  will have something similar.

Comment: SQL developer has a functionality named data modeler that takes your schema and generates an ERD but it is more convoluted than the fabric of spacetime and the Koch snowflake combined.

Comment: Of course, it can also show a list of all the tables that reference a given table, but it only shows the tables of the very first level in the hierarchy. If a table has 4 references, how do I know which of those will get me closer to the table I actually want to get to? And if the second table I choose also has another 4 references and so on, I end up spending 30-60 minutes just looking at all the tables to see in which way they link. I thought that a technology as mature as SQL would have some tool to just show me this info and not have me perform a manual breadth first search through it.

Comment: The scenario you just described is normal for a developer coming into a new code base. It’s part of the learning curve where we try to understand which tables contain which piece of information and how to get from point A to point B. The first few rounds can get involved but it gets easier over time as you get more familiar with the tables.